# SQL displaying a row with least value without using TOP

Tags: sql-server

im trying to list the row with the least value by not using the top function.
[image]

Here is my code,

```
> SELECT COUNT(SOH.SalesOrderNumber) AS NumberOfSales,  SP.Name FROM Person.StateProvince SP 
JOIN Person.Address A ON SP.StateProvinceID = A.StateProvinceID
JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory AS ST ON SP.TerritoryID = ST.TerritoryID
JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress BEA ON A.AddressID = BEA.AddressID
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH ON BEA.BusinessEntityID = SOH.CustomerID
WHERE ST.Name = 'Australia'
GROUP BY SP.Name
```

Ideally, the result should be 
NumberOfSale Name
94 Tasmania

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be an alternative:

```
SELECT NumberOfSales
    ,NAME
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(SOH.SalesOrderNumber) AS NumberOfSales
        , SP.NAME
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY COUNT(SOH.SalesOrderNumber)) RN
    FROM Person.StateProvince SP
    INNER JOIN Person.Address A
        ON SP.StateProvinceID = A.StateProvinceID
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory AS ST
        ON SP.TerritoryID = ST.TerritoryID
    INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress BEA
        ON A.AddressID = BEA.AddressID
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
        ON BEA.BusinessEntityID = SOH.CustomerID
    WHERE ST.NAME = 'Australia'
    GROUP BY SP.NAME
    ) RS
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I have errors with the NumberOfSales, Name on the first line. (Invalid Column Name)
As well as Where RN at the end. (Invalid Syntax Near Where, Expecting AS, ID or Quoted_ID) (Invalid Column Name for RN)

Comment: @KinLoo Try now, I forgot to add an alias for the result set.